# Javascript : making separate form submits

Tags: javascript

This is my javascript , i am manually writing a Stress Test for my web site by making 4 virtual users .

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
function test() {
var myStringArray = [ "user1", "user2" , "user3" , "user4" ]
var len = myStringArray.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {
document.inform.cid.value=myStringArray[0];
document.inform.pw.value="xxxxxx";
document.inform.submit();
}
}
</script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <form name="inform" method="post"  target="newWin" action="http://localhost:8080/logon?debug=1">
  <input type="text" name="cid" >
 <input type="password" name="pw" />
<input type="hidden" name="throttle" value="999" />
    <input type="submit" value="go" onclick="test()">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

When i ran the above program , its submitting only once , that is with the last user .

My requirement is that , i want to open 4 new windows with 4 virtual users .

Please let me know , how can i open 4 new windows with 4 virtual users .

Thanks .

Comment: You first need to change `document.inform.cid.value=myStringArray[0];` with `document.inform.cid.value=myStringArray[i];` because it's only using the first item in your array.

Comment: That's no program, that's a HTML page. It runs in a browser which makes the simulation of virtual users (with different sessions) complicated - rather write a real program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give different values for the form's `target` attribute for them to open up in new windows/tabs:

For example:

```
for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {

    document.inform.target = i; // a different target each time

    document.inform.cid.value=myStringArray[0];
    document.inform.pw.value="xxxxxx";
    document.inform.submit();
}
```

Check this **demo** (*uses jQuery but the concepts are the same*): http://jsfiddle.net/dvJMx/

---

**Edit**

to introduce a delay between each submit, you can do something like:

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/dvJMx/1/

```
var windowCounter = 1; // make sure you declare this globally

for (var i=0; i<len; ++i) {

    setTimeout(function() {
        document.inform.target = windowCounter++; // a different target each time

        document.inform.cid.value=myStringArray[0];
        document.inform.pw.value="xxxxxx";
        document.inform.submit();

    }, i*1000); // change 1000 to the interval you need in milliseconds

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , its working good ,all these requests are simultaneous, is it possible to keep a time gap between each submit ?? Thanks once again .

Comment: The delay code is giving me errors , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13256479/cr-ns-error-not-available-when-running-a-simple-javascript